# В чем ошибка при авторизации в laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel

Уже 3 день бьюсь. Перекинул проект на shared, все работает, все заносится в бд, регистрация, и если авторизация с запомнить меня, токен тоже заносится в базу. При авторизации пишет все ок, ошибок нету, должно кинуть в личный кабинет, но опять кидает на страницу авторизации, на локалке делал все отлично работает. На хостинге такая беда.

При заходе на сайт создаются куки laravel_session, и + еще одна кука со именем значения laravel_session. В общем уже незнаю что делать, проект стоит...

Папке storage и дочерним ее дал доступ 777, перепробовал все драйвера. Никак.
В .htaccess посоветовали добавить php_value session.save_path /home/c/cc28312/creamake/tmp, добавил, но не помогло.

p.s. с laravel работаю 3 мясаца, это первый проект на нем. И насчет драйвера  database. Не знаю как точно с ним работал создал миграцию session:table и все, авторизация простая Auth::attempt.

Comment: Что в логах laravel ?

Comment: Есть ли у вас на хостинге в ссылке символ "_" и какой браузер используете?

Comment: ну файл index в папке public_html использую хром.

Comment: попробовал через database данные заносятся, но все также, не авторизовывается

Comment: логи покажите. без них ничего не понятно

Comment: попробуйте настроить ссылку без _

Comment: Права папкам дал 777 в частности storage?